# Slow result from "GLOB" SQL command

Tags: android, sqlite, glob

I have a table (rowID, name, familyName) with at least 100.000 rows (SQLite). I am using this code to query my table when the text of an EditText changes (onTextChanged):

```
mySelectSql = "Select rowID from gamtable WHERE name GLOB ' " + searchEditText.getText().toString() + "*';";
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(mySelectSql, null);
```

rowID is primary key, and name is indexed! This code runs slowly (~6000ms) just on the **first** key that entered in the EditText, and works fast and very fast on second, third, etc.

I need to improve my code to result in first entered key as fast as second and third one...
Any help on this issue?

Comment: Most UI widgets like this won't preview with less than 3 characters entered.  What are the chances that showing all names starting with one letter will be *meaningful* to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's actually using an index (sounds like you've checked?), I would simply limit the number of results.  Using the maximum number of displayable results in the UI preview.

```
SELECT rowID FROM gamtable WHERE name GLOB 'foo*' LIMIT 15;
```